# Replacing a Dictionary Value without CS0200

Tags: c#

I have the following code, which is iterating through a JSON file where I need to replace all values with a specific character.  Note that translationDictionary is of the following type, because I do not know any of the keys at compile time:

`Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>?`

In this case I'm just replacing them with "*":

```
foreach (var key in translationDictionary)
{
    foreach (var entry in key.Value)
    {
        var replaceString = new string("*".ToCharArray()[0], entry.Value.Length);
        key.Value = replaceString;
    }
}
```

This gives me a CS0200 error because the property is read-only.

[image: CS0200]

I have tried some form of creating a totally new entry and swapping it out, but I'm not sure if it's the correct approach.  I am also running into trouble because it's currently being used as the iteration variable:

```
var newEntry = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(entry.Key, replaceString);
```

How can I properly modify this code such that the `entry`'s values are replaced with my `replaceString` variable?

Comment: you modify a dict-entry using its indexer: `myDict[myIndex] = myValue`. Anyway you cannot modify the dictionary while iterating it, you need to create a new one.

Comment: `"*".ToCharArray()[0]` is there a problem with a simple `'*'`?

Comment: @Ralf Nope, modified now thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to modify dictionary entry - use dictionary indexer: `someDict[key] = newValue`. In your case that would be:

```
foreach (var key in translationDictionary) {
    foreach (var entry in key.Value) {
        // no need to do "*".ToCharArray()[0] by the way
        key.Value[entry.Key] = new string('*', entry.Value.Length);
    }
}
```